# how to configure activti 5.17 with ldap

Tags: configuration, ldap, activiti

Can You Please guide me How Can I configure "activiti" 5.17 and ldap ?
as ldap xml configuration file is not there in 'activiti 5.17' (activiti-cfg-context.xml is missing in 5.17)
I tried to configure "ldap" in "activiti-custom-context.xml" file but then 'activiti' wont boot up again.
i tried to find out but nothing helped me,
if u have done integration then please help me !
Any response will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls check if the following URLs are helpful

http://thysmichels.com/2014/05/25/activiti-bpm-tutorial-ldap/

https://forums.activiti.org/content/ldap-authentication-issue

https://forums.activiti.org/content/steps-integrate-activiti-ldap